# Converting a cisco wildcard mask to list of IPNetworks in Python

Tags: python, ip, wildcard, mask, cisco

So, cisco routers [allow](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/secursw/ps1018/products_tech_note09186a00800a5b9a.shtml#topic2) one to specify ACLs using what are called wildcard masks. Wildcard masks specify a group of hosts using a 32-bit long integer, but they differ from the typical netmask in that when a bit is 0 in wildcard mask, it represents a compulsory match and when it is 1, then it is a wildcard. Some folks (even cisco) call it inverse mask, and the fact is that all netmasks can be coverted into wildcard masks by simple inversion, but not the other way around. Because you can have wildcard mask that can look like this:

0.0.255.0
0.0.255.254
0.255.0.254
and so on.

which really has no equivalent netmasks

What I want to do (and hope that somebody has already done something like this), is to convert a generic wildcard into a collection of equivalent CIDR blocks. It would be very nice if the solution is in Python (i.e. the output generates the infamous netaddr IPNetwork objects), but if you really just have an efficient algorithm to solve this, I would take it.

Answer (score 3):

in Python 2.7:

```
import ipaddress

mask = u"0.1.2.7"
address = u"172.18.161.2"

def wildcard_mask_test (test_octet, acl_octet, acl_wildcard_octet):
    #Test one number against acl address and mask
    #Bitwise OR of test_octet and acl_octet against the octet of the wildcard mask
    test_result = test_octet | acl_wildcard_octet
    acl_result  = acl_octet | acl_wildcard_octet
    #Return value is whether they match
    return (acl_result == test_result)

def test_octet (acl_octet, acl_wildcard_octet):
    matches = []
    #Test all possible numbers in an octet (0..255) against octet of acl and mask
    #Short circuit here for a mask value of 0 since it matches only the $acl_octet
    if (acl_wildcard_octet == 0):
        matches.append(acl_octet)
        return matches
    else:
        for test_octet in range(0,256):
            if (wildcard_mask_test(test_octet, acl_octet, acl_wildcard_octet)):
                matches.append(test_octet)
        return matches

def list_of_matches_acl (acl_address, acl_mask):
    #Pass in the variables of ACL network and wildcard mask
    #eg 10.200.128.0 0.0.0.255
    potential_matches=[]
    #Split the incoming parameters into 4 octets
    acl_address_octets = acl_address.split('.')
    for n in range(0,4):
        acl_address_octets[n] = int(acl_address_octets[n])

    acl_mask_octets = acl_mask.split('.')
    for n in range(0,4):
        acl_mask_octets[n] = int(acl_mask_octets[n])

    #Test the 1st octet
    matches_octet_1_ref = test_octet(acl_address_octets[0], acl_mask_octets[0])
    #Test the 2nd octet
    matches_octet_2_ref = test_octet(acl_address_octets[1], acl_mask_octets[1])
    #Test the 3rd octet
    matches_octet_3_ref = test_octet(acl_address_octets[2], acl_mask_octets[2])
    #Test the 4th octet
    matches_octet_4_ref = test_octet(acl_address_octets[3], acl_mask_octets[3])

    #Assemble the list of possible matches
    #Iterating over all options for each octet
    for n1 in matches_octet_1_ref:
        for n2 in matches_octet_2_ref:
            for n3 in matches_octet_3_ref:
                for n4 in matches_octet_4_ref:
                    potential_matches.append(str(n1)+'.'+str(n2)+'.'+str(n3)+'.'+str(n4))
    ip = []
    for m in potential_matches:
        ip.append(ipaddress.ip_address(unicode(m)))
    out = list(ipaddress.collapse_addresses(ip))
    return out



a = list_of_matches_acl (address, mask)
print a
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

First count how many consecutive 1's you have from the right end. That'll determine the size of the CIDR blocks.

Each remaining wildcard will double the number of CIDR blocks you have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the most common scenario is "wildcard mask is exactly the inverse of the subnet mask" and your examples like `0.0.255.0` aren't typical. However, I *think* this will do what you ask. Using Python 3.3's [ipaddress module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ipaddress.html):

```
import ipaddress

mask = "0.0.255.0"
address = "172.18.161.1"

mask_int = int.from_bytes((ipaddress.IPv4Address(mask).packed), "big")
address_int = int.from_bytes(ipaddress.IPv4Address(address).packed, "big")

lower = ipaddress.IPv4Address((2 ** 32 - 1 - mask_int) & address_int)
upper = ipaddress.IPv4Address(mask_int | address_int)

subnet_range = list(ipaddress.summarize_address_range(lower, upper))
```

In the example we'd replace the third octet of `172.18.161.1` with wildcards, i.e. `172.18.x.1` with x ranging from 0 to 255. So our range would be `172.18.0.1` through `172.18.255.1`. The summary blocks for those are in the `subnet_range` list:

```
172.18.0.1/32
172.18.0.2/31
172.18.0.4/30
172.18.0.8/29
172.18.0.16/28
172.18.0.32/27
172.18.0.64/26
172.18.0.128/25
172.18.1.0/24
172.18.2.0/23
172.18.4.0/22
172.18.8.0/21
172.18.16.0/20
172.18.32.0/19
172.18.64.0/18
172.18.128.0/18
172.18.192.0/19
172.18.224.0/20
172.18.240.0/21
172.18.248.0/22
172.18.252.0/23
172.18.254.0/24
172.18.255.0/31
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while trying to solve this problem myself and ended up writing some new perl code to do it so I thought I'd share

It's not optimized or elegant (yet) but it works and should hopefully be very clear as to what it's doing.

```
list_of_matches('10.48.140.82' , '0.0.0.1')
```

returns:

```
10.48.140.82 10.48.140.83
```

and

```
list_of_matches('10.48.140.82' , '0.1.0.1')
```

returns:

```
10.48.140.82 10.48.140.83 10.49.140.82 10.49.140.83
```

and

```
list_of_matches('10.48.140.82' , '0.1.5.1')
```

returns:

```
10.48.136.82 10.48.136.83 10.48.137.82 10.48.137.83 10.48.140.82 10.48.140.83 10.48.141.82 10.48.141.83 10.49.136.82 10.49.136.83 10.49.137.82 10.49.137.83 10.49.140.82 10.49.140.83 10.49.141.82 10.49.141.83
```

code:

```
sub list_of_matches_acl {

    #Pass in the variables of ACL network and wildcard mask
    #eg 10.200.128.0 0.0.0.255
    my ( $acl_address, $acl_mask ) = @_;

    #The array of possible matches
    my @potential_matches;

    #Split the incoming parameters into 4 octets
    my @acl_address_octets = split /\./, $acl_address;
    my @acl_mask_octets    = split /\./, $acl_mask;

    #Test the 1st octet
    my $matches_octet_1_ref
        = test_octet( $acl_address_octets[0], $acl_mask_octets[0] );

    #Copy the referenced array into a new one
    my @one = @{$matches_octet_1_ref};

    #Test the 2nd octet
    my $matches_octet_2_ref
        = test_octet( $acl_address_octets[1], $acl_mask_octets[1] );

    #Copy the referenced array into a new one
    my @two = @{$matches_octet_2_ref};

    #Test the 3rd octet
    my $matches_octet_3_ref
        = test_octet( $acl_address_octets[2], $acl_mask_octets[2] );

    #Copy the referenced array into a new one
    my @three = @{$matches_octet_3_ref};

    #Test the 4th octet
    my $matches_octet_4_ref
        = test_octet( $acl_address_octets[3], $acl_mask_octets[3] );

    #Copy the referenced array into a new one
    my @four = @{$matches_octet_4_ref};

    #Assemble the list of possible matches
    #Iterating over all options for each octet
    foreach my $octet1 (@one) {
        foreach my $octet2 (@two) {
            foreach my $octet3 (@three) {
                foreach my $octet4 (@four) {

                    #Save this potential match to the array of matches
                    #say "$octet1.$octet2.$octet3.$octet4"
                    push( @potential_matches,
                        "$octet1.$octet2.$octet3.$octet4" );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return \@potential_matches;
}

sub test_octet {

    #Test all possible numbers in an octet (0..255) against octet of acl and mask
    my ( $acl_octet, $acl_wildcard_octet ) = @_;

    my @matches;

    #Short circuit here for a mask value of 0 since it matches only the $acl_octet
    if ( $acl_wildcard_octet eq 0 ) {
        push @matches, $acl_octet;
    }
    else {
        for my $test_octet ( 0 .. 255 ) {
            if (wildcard_mask_test(
                    $test_octet, $acl_octet, $acl_wildcard_octet
                )
                )
            {
                #If this value is a match, save it
                push @matches, $test_octet;
            }

        }
    }

    #Return which values from 0..255 match
    return \@matches;
}

sub wildcard_mask_test {

    #Test one number against acl address and mask
    my ( $test_octet, $acl_octet, $acl_wildcard_octet ) = @_;

    #Bitwise OR of test_octet and acl_octet against the octet of the wildcard mask
    my $test_result = $test_octet | $acl_wildcard_octet;
    my $acl_result  = $acl_octet | $acl_wildcard_octet;

    #Return value is whether they match
    return ( $acl_result eq $test_result );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 generic implementation (both v4 and v6), using the builtin ipaddress module:

```
import itertools
from ipaddress import NetmaskValueError
import ipaddress


MAX_DONT_CARE_BITS = 8


def acl_with_wildcard_to_netmasks(address_str: str, wildcard_str: str):
    """
    Translates an ACL (address, wildcard) to a list of ip_network objects (address, netmask)
    :param address_str: IP address string (v4 or v6)
    :param wildcard_str: wildcard mask (v4 or v6)
    :return: list of IP networks

    E.G for address="172.18.161.2" and wildcard "0.1.2.7"
    it returns:
        [IPv4Network('172.18.161.0/29'), IPv4Network('172.18.163.0/29'),
        IPv4Network('172.19.161.0/29'), IPv4Network('172.19.163.0/29')]
    """

    ip_addr = ipaddress.ip_address(address_str)
    wildcard = ipaddress.ip_address(wildcard_str)

    if wildcard.version != ip_addr.version:
        raise ValueError(f"IP version mismtach: address_str({address_str}), wildcard_str({wildcard_str})")

    # default values for v4
    _length = ipaddress.IPV4LENGTH
    _net_cls = ipaddress.IPv4Network
    if wildcard.version == 6:
        # values for v6
        _length = ipaddress.IPV6LENGTH
        _net_cls = ipaddress.IPv6Network

    mask_bits = [int(b) for b in format(int(wildcard), F"0{_length}b")]

    # We keep count of zero bits position (left-most is 0)
    dont_care_bits_index = [i for i, e in enumerate(reversed(mask_bits)) if e == 1]

    # We count how many contiguous zeros are from left-most bit, and we will mask them with a netmask
    hostmask_length = 0
    for (pos, bit) in enumerate(dont_care_bits_index):
        if pos != bit:
            break
        hostmask_length += 1

    # We only keep the bits that can't be dealt with by a netmask and need to be expanded to cartesian product
    dont_care_to_expand_index = dont_care_bits_index[hostmask_length:]

    # reverse in order to have the final loop iterate last through high order bits
    dont_care_to_expand_index.reverse()

    if len(dont_care_to_expand_index) > MAX_DONT_CARE_BITS:
        raise NetmaskValueError(f"{wildcard_str} contains more than {MAX_DONT_CARE_BITS} non-contiguous wildcard bits")

    ip_int_original = int(ip_addr)
    subnets = []
    for bits_values in itertools.product((0,1), repeat=len(dont_care_to_expand_index)):
        # enforce the bits_values in the IP address
        ip_int = ip_int_original
        for (index, val) in zip(dont_care_to_expand_index, bits_values):
            sb_mask = 1 << index
            if val:
                ip_int |= sb_mask
            else:
                ip_int &= ~sb_mask

        subnets.append(_net_cls((ip_int, _length-hostmask_length), strict=False))

    return subnets


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # IPv4
    a4 = [ipaddress.IPv4Network('172.18.161.0/29'), ipaddress.IPv4Network('172.18.163.0/29'),
         ipaddress.IPv4Network('172.19.161.0/29'), ipaddress.IPv4Network('172.19.163.0/29')]
    b4 = acl_with_wildcard_to_netmasks('172.18.161.2', '0.1.2.7')
    print(b4)
    print(f"Lists are equal: {a4 == b4} (length {len(a4)})")

    # IPv6
    a6 = [ipaddress.IPv6Network('eed0:feff::/64'), ipaddress.IPv6Network('eed0:ffff::/64'),
          ipaddress.IPv6Network('fed0:feff::/64'), ipaddress.IPv6Network('fed0:ffff::/64')]
    b6 = acl_with_wildcard_to_netmasks('fed0:ffff::1', '1000:0100:0000:0000:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff')
    print(b6)
    print(f"Lists are equal: {a6 == b6} (length {len(a6)})")
```

Maybe also a comment on what is this useful for: one concrete use case is translating generic ACLs (using wildcard syntax) to a Juniper QFX10k configuration (the hardware only supports netmasks).

Answer (score 0):

Example how to convert Cisco ACL wildcard to prefixes

```
from cisco_acl import Address

address = Address("10.0.0.0 0.0.3.3")
prefixes = address.prefixes()
print(prefixes)
# ['10.0.0.0/30', '10.0.1.0/30', '10.0.2.0/30', '10.0.3.0/30']
```